# Need to split an array based on another array containing size Python

Tags: python, arrays, mapping

I have 2 arrays - one containing data and the other containing a size that the data needs to be broken into:

```
data = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]
size = [1,2]
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
data = [{"a":1} , {"b":2,"c":3}]
```

I'm basically trying to do this without doing a bunch of for loops but I'm still new to python. Anything more performant than looping through?

Comment: Why don't you want to use *for* loops? You could probably construct some convoluted [almost] impossible to read list/dictionary comprehension to do this but why make things hard for yourself?

Comment: Echo with earlier post, this is not the best way to `learn` a new language. Try to do `loop` first, and share with community for `optimize` - if there's a valid reason.  BTW, this is a `list` not an `array` in strict Python terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the code by using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
and [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). Note that these are versions of loops, so while the code is shorter than that using `for` loops, it still has a bunch of loops, essentially. But there is no way to avoid loops altogether in one form or another:

```
from itertools import islice

data = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]
size = [1,2]

data_dct = data[0]
data_keys = list(data_dct.keys())
it = iter(data_keys)

sliced_data_keys = [list(islice(it, 0, s)) for s in size]

sliced_data = []
for lst in sliced_data_keys:
    sliced_data.append({k: data_dct[k] for k in lst})

print(sliced_data)
# [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding OP's apparent aversion to *for* loops, here's an example that does use *for* loops but does not rely on any additional module imports.

```
data = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}]

size = [1, 2]

assert len(data[0]) == sum(size) # otherwise this won't work

new_data = []

items = iter(data[0].items())

for s in size:
    new_data.append({})
    for _ in range(s):
        k, v = next(items)
        new_data[-1][k] = v

print(new_data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
data = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}]
size = [1, 2]

items, start = list(data[0].items()), 0
out = [dict(items[start : (start := start + s)]) for s in size]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
```